# Spark - Creating a Dataframe from the cartesian product of two arrays in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I have two arrays:

```
val customers = Array("Alice", "Bob", "Mike","Charly")
val customersLen = customers.length 
val items = Array("milk", "bread", "butter", "apples", "oranges")
val itemsLen = items.length 
val size = (customersLen*itemsLen)-1
```

I can create in an array the cartesian products of these two arrays like this:

```
val cartesianProd= for(i <- 0 to size) yield (customers(i % customersLen ),items(i % itemsLen ))
```

The output would be:

> cartesianProd: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(String, String)]
>   = Vector((Alice,milk), (Bob,bread), (Mike,butter), (Charly,apples), (Alice,oranges), (Bob,milk), (Mike,bread), (Charly,butter),
>   (Alice,apples), (Bob,oranges), (Mike,milk), (Charly,bread),
>   (Alice,butter), (Bob,apples), (Mike,oranges), (Charly,milk),
>   (Alice,bread), (Bob,butter), (Mike,apples), (Charly,oranges))

Now I would like to generate a Dataframe from this array. Reusing the previous logic, so I wrote:

```
val dfCustItem = Seq(for(i <- 0 to size ) yield(customers (i % customersLen ),items(i % itemsLen ))).toDF("customer","item")
```

But I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of
>   columns doesn't match. Old column names (1): value New column names
>   (2): name, item   at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.toDF(Dataset.scala:397)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DatasetHolder.toDF(DatasetHolder.scala:44)   ...
>   48 elided

As I understand this is because yield return the pair(customer,item) in a single column named value, and toDF is expecting two independent columns (not sure if the names of this columns is relevant or not)

How can I solve this issue? that is to yield the output of the loop in two independent columns

Comment: Why not convert each array into DataFrame and then do a cartesian product of those Dataframes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `Seq` so just removing that should work

```
val dfCustItem = (for(i <- 0 to size ) yield(customers (i % customersLen ),items(i % itemsLen ))).toDF("customer","item")
```

**Explanation:**

As you can see that `for(i <- 0 to size) yield (customers(i % customersLen ),items(i % itemsLen ))` is already `scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(String, String)]` and adding a `Seq` will generate `Seq[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(String, String)]]` whereas you need is `Tuple2` elements inside `Seq`